# Using builder in Kivy

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, builder

I want to create a simple app that has GUI with a button that allows me to vibrate an android phone. Im using a .kv file for the layout and the Builder in my .yp file

.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from plyer import vibrator


class AndroidApp(GridLayout):
    def vibrate(self):
        vibrator.vibrate()


kv = Builder.load_file("android_app.kv")


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
<AndroidApp>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text:"Android Vibrate"

            Button:
                text:"Android Vibrate"
                on_press:
                    root.vibrate()
```

When I try to run the app, I get the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7Kla.png)

This should be straightforward app but somehow  I find a way to make it crash. The android_app.py & .kv files are in the same folder. Any ideas why the window wont be created? I aprreciate any help.
Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Presumably all kivy apps fail the same way?

Comment: Have you installed the dependencies, kivy_deps.sdl2 etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the main class, not the result from building. Here I'm using `Builder.load_string()` for convenience, and not importing `player`, but otherwise the only substantive change is that I changed `return kv` to `return AndroidApp()`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
#:import utils kivy.utils
<AndroidApp>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text:"Android Vibrate"

            Button:
                text:"Android Vibrate"
                on_press:
                    root.vibrate()
'''

class AndroidApp(GridLayout):
    def vibrate(self):
        vibrator.vibrate()


Builder.load_string(KV)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AndroidApp()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: took me a while but your suggestion did the trick..should have returned the main class..thanks for your help